# How can I turn these python lines as a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, spyder

I need help with this, how can I write these lines as a list comprehension

```
   t_averaged = []
   for i in range(len(i_averaged)-1):
     t_av = t[i_averaged [i] ]+ time_intervall /2
     t_averaged.append(t_av )
```

Comment: first learn how to use `for`-loop  without `range(len(..))`

Comment: what did you try ? it should be converted to list comprehension almost without changes.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
t_averaged = [
    t[i_averaged[i]] + time_intervall/2
        for i in range(len(i_averaged)-1)
]
```

and without `range(len(...))`

```
t_averaged = [
    t[item] + time_intervall/2
        for item in i_averaged[:-1]
]
```

Comment: The `i_averaged[:-1]` is faithful to the original code in the question, which is good. However, I suspect that the use of `range(len(..) - 1)` was an error in the original code:  it's possible the OP really meant to loop over all elements of `i_averaged`.

Comment: @NicholasM probably you are right. `len()-1` was strange for me too but OP said nothing about problem so I keep it.